# sweetalert isConfirm with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, confirm, sweetalert

I have a sample [code here](https://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/yug081tv/1/) where i wanted to continue or add new value using `isConfirm` with sweet alert as.

```
 swal({
      title: "Are you sure?",
      text: "Save the name",
      type: "warning",
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
      confirmButtonText: "Save and Add Another",
      cancelButtonText: "New",
      closeOnConfirm: true,
      closeOnCancel: true
    }, function(isConfirm) {
      if (isConfirm) {
        // saves the input values & selected values using ajax call
        $scope.test = '';
      } else {
       // reset input values & selected values and fresh input again
        $scope.test = '';
        $scope.mysel = '-1';
      }
    });
```

But after clicking save and add another button the model value didn't clears at first time. Also it didn't resets on clicking of `New`. What is wrong with code?

Comment: You could post at least the link of the module that you're using.

Comment: Link of the module??  Given in fiddle.

Comment: Yes, the `sweet alert`.

Comment: Sorry.. Didn't get you.. I am using http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `$scope.$apply();`, otherwise it will not reflect the value in `$scope` variable.

<kbd>[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/yug081tv/2/)</kbd>

You can check [here](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html) more info about `$scope.apply()`.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Wanted exactly same. BTW Nice tutorial in the link... :)